# Is there a trimmed version of AWS Jar file for S3

Tags: aws-java-sdk

I downloaded AWS SDK for Java. The JAR file is around 80MB. Is there a smaller version for just S3. I do not need other stacks and am wonder if I can trim this JAR file down a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check the [SDK setup instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/setup-install.html#include-sdk). There are artifacts published for every module. So if you only need S3, you can add just it to your Maven project:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.297</version>
  </dependency>
```

Or if you're using another build tool, see the linked instructions. You can also find the published artifact on Maven Central: [`com.amazonaws : aws-java-sdk-s3 : 1.11.297`](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.amazonaws%7Caws-java-sdk-s3%7C1.11.297%7Cjar).